# How do I reference a nested key in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a task in ansible that greps a list of emails in a loop. I am trying to get the "stdout_lines" output of this.

```
vars:
  emails:
    - test@email.com
tasks:
  - name: search
    register: found
    shell: "grep -i {{item}} ~/file"
    with_items: "{{emails}}"
debug:
  msg: "{{found.results}}"
```

The above displays the following:

```
"msg": {
    "changed": true, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "grep -i test@email.com ~/file", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.003060", 
            "end": "2020-10-19 12:52:29.930458", 
            "failed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "grep -i test@email.com ~/x", 
                    "_uses_shell": true, 
                    "argv": null, 
                    "chdir": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "executable": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "stdin": null, 
                    "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                    "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                    "warn": true
                }
            }, 
            "item": "test@email.com", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2020-10-19 12:52:29.927398", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "test@email.com line 1\ntest@email.com line2", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "test@email.com line 1", 
                "test@email.com line 2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I try

```
debug:
  msg: "{{found.results.stdout_lines}}"
```

I get the error

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
> with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no
> attribute 'stdout_lines'

I should also note that I run into issues when I have more than one email in the list, but one problem at at time.

Comment: results is a list of elements, and you see its 1st (and only) element. you should access it by: `msg: "{{found.results[0].stdout_lines}}"`

Answer (score 0):

When you run an Ansible module in a loop, like you have done here with the `shell` module, the `results` key is a list ([docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)).

> When you use register with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a results attribute that is a list of all responses from the module. This differs from the data structure returned when using register without a loop.

Since `found.results` is a list of objects it doesn't have a `stdout_lines` key itself, rather each of its items do. Depending on what you need you could access the key on the first item:

```
found.results[0].stdout_lines
```

You could [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with) over each item again and do something with each:

```
- name: Do something with output
  example:
    var: "{{ item }}"
  loop: found.results
```

You could run the [map filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) over it, for example to concatenate the lines in each `stdout_lines` item:

```
found.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | join('\n')
```